# How can I send data:audio/ogg; code=opus;base64 to speech to text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

Sorry for my English, I'm Brazilian I searched a lot and the only thing that I found was how to send an audio file to Speech to Text. I found the ideia, what I have to do but, I don't know in the sintaxe in nodejs, javascript. The audio is like this data:audio/ogg; code=opus;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAC8IgAAAAAAAEyQvCMBE0...
script.js

```
mediaRecorder.onstop=() =>{
      const blob = new Blob(partesAudio,{type:'audio/ogg; code=opus'})
      const reader = new window.FileReader()
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob)


      reader.onloadend= async () =>{
        //
      /*const audio = document.createElement('audio')
      audio.src = reader.result
      audio.controls = true
      $('body').append(audio)*/
      //
      console.log(reader.result)
      var resultado= await  fetch('http://localhost:3000/fala/',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              fala:reader.result //'frase8.wav'
            }),
          });...
```

app.js

```
    app.post('/fala/', async(req, res) => {
     let falado=FALA(req.body.fala).then(frase=>{return frase}).catch(()=>{
    console.log("erro")
    });
     falado.then(function(result){
        res.json(result);
      })
```

speechtotext.js

```
var SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
var fs = require('fs');
var speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
  iam_apikey: '**********************',
  url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api'
});



var fala= async function(nomeAudio){
return new Promise(async function(resolve,reject){
  var params = {
    audio: nomeAudio,//fs.createReadStream('audio.ogg')
    content_type: 'audio/ogg',
    model: 'pt-BR_BroadbandModel',

  };


speechToText.recognize(params, function (error, transcript) {
console.log('chegou');
  if (error || transcript.results.length === 0)
      resolve(error);
  else
      resolve( transcript.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript);
});

})
}

module.exports=fala;
```

Comment: Please show us the code you tried.

Comment: Sure, Now  you can see

Comment: Can you please format the code properly, it is hard to track what is going there? What is the problem you have with your code? It seems ok.